# Qt: What governs mouse event emission rate?

Tags: qt, events, callback, pyqt4, mouse

I have a callback that does some work when the mouse is moved.  It feels weird not to govern it to a maximum rate. What governs how often mouse callbacks occur when the user moves the mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mouse device driver. If you change mouse settings on the configuration panel of your system you will see a behavior difference. The window system send those events to the main process, which are handled by the `QApplication` and then propagated to the right widget.

Unless no event filter has been set, the events delivery at a widget is as seamless as in a native app. After all the Qt event system match what different OS use for their window event system.

If something feels weird double check your callback implementation. It is very unlikely that the issue is somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on the mouse’s polling rate. Mouse polling rate is how often it reports its position (measured in Hz). For example a mouse with 125 Hz polling reports its position 125 times in a second (Every 8 milliseconds).

A higher polling rate can lead to a more callback in your case when you move the mouse. But it will also use more CPU resources.

Comment: I.e. in the case of USB, everything is based on a polling model initiated from the host. Something like: the mouse driver would submit an "interrupt URB" in which a poll rate is specified, and then the lower level host controller driver puts that polling into effect. On each poll, a message is sent to the USB device and a response is received.